# How to find position of Fifth blank space in string?

Tags: c#, string

I am new to .net web forms so can anyone help me on.

How to find position of Fifth blank space in string for asp.net ?

I have

```
string s="aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii kk"
```

So I want to make substring till fifth blank space so new string should be :

```
"aa bb cc dd ee"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the substring `"aa bb cc dd ee"`:

```
String.Join(" ", "aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii kk".Split(' ').Take(5))
```

And to find the position of the fifth space, as you asked originally:

```
"aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii kk".Split(' ').Take(5).Sum(a => a.Length + 1) - 1
```

Explanation:

- `.Split(' ')` - split your string on spaces, so we now have a `string[]` containing: `aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, kk`
- `.Take(5)` - take the first five elements of that array in an `IEnumerable<string>`: `aa, bb, cc, dd, ee`
- `.Sum(a => a.Length + 1)` - add together all the lengths of the individual elements (in this case, all `2` and add one for the missing space due to the split
- `- 1` to remove the extra count for the space

An alternative would be to to get `.Length` of the substring above.

Comment: One small adjustment - you can use `.Split()` - it splits by default by whitespaces

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Fair enough - I like to explicitly show what I'm splitting on - leaves less to the imagination :)

Comment: Really very thankful. i got answer for my both questions THANKS once again. cheers !!!

Comment: @Kohok Glad I could help and welcome to StackOverflow! On StackOverflow, if an answer to your question is the correct one, mark it as "Accepted" with the tick symbol underneath the score - you get 2 points for doing so too :)

Comment: @Kohok Added explanation to make clear what I am doing.

Answer (score 4):

You could split the string, take only the first 5 substrings, then join it back together, like this:

```
string s = "aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii kk";
string output = String.Join(" ", s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 6).Take(5)); 
Console.WriteLine(output); // "aa bb cc dd ee"
```

Or for a more direct method, just use `IndexOf` until you've found the number of spaces you want:

```
string s = "aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii kk";
var index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    index = s.IndexOf(" ", index + 1);
}

string output = s.Remove(index);
Console.WriteLine(output); // "aa bb cc dd ee"
```

Comment: Really very thankful. i got answer for my both questions THANKS once again. cheers !!! –

Answer (score 2):

Or...

```
var nrOfBlanks = 0;
var firstFive = new String(s.TakeWhile(c => 
                                        (nrOfBlanks += (c == ' ' ? 1 : 0)) < 5)
                             .ToArray());
```

... just because string-manipulations using slightly too complex Linq-expressions feels so fun and sexy.

Comment: +1 on the inefficient but indeed extremely fun and sexy solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii kk";
var array = s.Split( new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string newstring = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     newstring += array[i] + " ";
Console.WriteLine(newstring.Trim());
```

Output will be;

```
aa bb cc dd ee
```

Here a <kbd>[`Demonstration`](http://ideone.com/NgAp1R)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

A linq version:

```
var fifthBlankIndex = s.Select((c, index) => new{ c, index })
 .Where(x => Char.IsWhiteSpace(x.c))
 .ElementAtOrDefault(4);

int result = -1;
if(fifthBlankIndex  != null)
    result = fifthBlankIndex.index;  // 14
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://ideone.com/TvjGWV)**</kbd>

**Edit** If you just want to take the first five words that's a completely different requirement:

```
string fiveWords = string.Join(" ", s.Split().Take(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.split(' ') this returns array of the strings.

```
string s = "aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii kk";
//
// Split string on spaces.
// ... This will separate all the words.
//
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

So once you get the array you can concatenate as many words you want. So in your case loop till 4th index in the words array and concatenate inserting blank in between.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `Substring` :

```
string Requiredpart= s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(' ', theString.IndexOf(' ') + 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split using the blank char

string[] words = s.Split(' ');

and then compose the words as you like.

I hope you find this useful.
Nicola